# How to interrupt the building of a Docker container in VSCode?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, remote-containers

Haven't found anyone else asking this question so this might have an obvious answer, but I'm new to web development and haven't been able to figure out yet (so here goes nothing)

If VSCode is unable to finish building a container because the Dockerfile build code is expecting an interaction, how does one **end the build process**??

I tried clicking on the [image]where it said "Opening remote..." as well as on VSCode's message box "Starting dev container (show log)" and there was no option to end the process. (that I saw!)

Restarting VSCode simply restarted the container building process, and searches in the documentation and on Google for "stop / end / interrupt opening remote container docker vscode" yielded nothing, so I'm forced to wonder:

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

In the end, I closed VSCode and moved the files so that the process crashed upon reopening VSCode (and I could edit the files and start the building process again successfully), but that seemed like a heavy-handed solution.

Any insights / advice welcome! Thank you!

Comment: I believe ctrl-C used to work and so this might be a regression in the extension.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the container button on the left bottom corner during the build

[container build button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB6Dn.png)

it gives this option to close the connection, which kills the build.

[close the connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqGVh.png)

Comment: Unfortunately this also closes the folder, so you need to open the folder back up. Ideally it stops the build and reopens the local folder.